# High-weight errors from ion trap crosstalk

Tags: error-correction, ion-trap-quantum-computing, trapped-ion

A basic assumption of various error correction threshold theorems is that the probability of an error exponentially decreases with the weight of the error.

One of the selling features of ion traps is that in a single trap, the qubits have all-to-all connectivity. For, e.g., LDPC codes, this is essential. But does this also mean that there is a much higher chance of high-weight, coherent errors (e.g., cross-talk)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before going further, I think it is worth pointing out that trapped ions have *any-to-any* rather than *all-to-all* coupling. With maybe a few exceptions, no one is doing anything more than two qubit gates.

The basic idea of trapped ion quantum computing is generally as follows. Typically, you encode the qubit state in the ion's spin (hyperfine/Zeeman qubits). To perform two qubit gates, you couple the ion's spin to it's motion by using focused lasers. Without those lasers, there is virtually zero coupling between spin and motion, which is the big feature of ion trap quantum computing. In fact, this lack of coupling is what makes two qubit gates rather challenging technically - you have to use a considerable amount of laser power for a relatively long time to do gates. So the way crosstalk errors occur is actually quite local - the nonzero spot size of the lasers means that neighboring qubits will undergo unintended gate operations as well. However, since the laser intensity is gaussian in space, the effects on even next-nearest neighbors are exponentially small.

However, it is worth pointing out that gates can and do introduce motional heating if they are imperfect. The idea being that a perfect gate returns the motional state of each ion back to where it started, but imperfect gates leave a bit of motion left over. You may think that this motional heating will mess up gates coming afterwards. However, a main selling point of the Molmer-Sorenson gate with ions is that it works regardless of the initial state of the motional degrees of freedom. So while this heating does affect gate fidelity, it does not cascade and propagate errors in the way you might be wondering.

Comment: You say "you couple the ion's spin to it's motion" to describe a 2 qubit gate, but such a gate needs to apply to 2 different ions, right? If those two ions are far apart, how do they communicate for the 2 qubit gate? Can that process create high-weight errors?

Comment: Good question, their spins are both coupled to a vibrational mode of the ion crystal. While other ions will definitely feel this vibration as well, their spins are not coupled to the vibration *unless* they are exposed to lasers at the right frequency. Hence why the beam spot size must be tightly focused in these experiments.

Comment: Thanks, so maybe to condense my original line of thought: the beam spot size will not be perfect, so there is presumably a *bit* of erroneous vibrational coupling. That seems like it will be a "high weight" term, i.e., it will be all-to-all (but maybe that's wrong). If it is a high-weight term, then even if it's small now (say $<10^{-5}$, even), it won't get any smaller with the usual QECC. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Are you talking about all-to-all or any-to-any? This type of crosstalk will only affect neighboring qubits at a given gate, not next nearest neighbors etc.

Comment: All-to-all. Lets say I deliberately coupled all ions in the trap to the same vibrational mode. You said that kind of coupling can create interactions between distant ions; would it create an all-to-all interaction in this case? If so, when we de-couple the spin and vibration, we end up with a non-negligible part of the state still coupled thanks to errors, and would such errors add up to a non-negligible coupling of *every* ion (e.g., once we've applied a 2-qubit gate to each ion at least once)?

Comment: Good thoughts! In practice the way experiments are actually done it's a bit different that what your imagining. While the initial error from a single two qubit gate will leave some tiny amount of motional entanglement, you are also actively laser cooling the motional degrees of freedom before and after the gate. So in effect the motional state is *measured* before and after every gate (but not during) and I would say that the kind of error you're thinking of wouldn't occur.

Comment: Thinking about this more: measuring this will remove those high-weight terms with high probability, but with some probability (say, $10^{-5}$) the measurement of the motional state will collapse it into a coupling of every ion. Can that coupling be corrected?

Comment: @SamJaques During the measurement of the motional state the spin-motion coupling is turned off, so the only states which can be collapsed are the two qubits involved in the preceding two-qubit gate. So if you do the motional measurement/cooling with every two-qubit gate, then you do not get the coupling are you describing with any probability. I hope I understood your thoughts correctly

Comment: @SamJaques that said, there are protocols which don't include as frequent motional cooling, which gives rise to correlated errors like you are thinking of https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.106.130506